# Compile Python GUI Kivy framework program using Cython

Tags: python, kivy, cython

I'm trying compile source code python GUI using `Kivy` framework. But I don't find solution to do it.

My project run on `Raspberry Pi`.

My project include:

```
|--main.py
|--main.kv
|--module1.py
|--module1.kv
....
```

I only want the others not easy read my source code. Because I want to commercialize.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the kv a string inside the .py file, instead of a file, and load it with `Builder.load_string()`. Then, you can use cython to make compiled modules (.so on linux/osx, .pyd on windows) from python files (you just need to create a simple `setup.py` file for it). Then you can use pyinstaller to create a fully distributable directory starting with your entry point (main.py).

The details to all this are a bit long to fit in a stackoverflow answer, but that's basically all the pieces you need.